# Object cannot be cast from DB Null or Other Types in C#

Tags: c#

I am getting error on this line whenever I press Add button on DataGridView.

```
DateTime PostedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(selectedRow.Cells[2].Value);
```

> DateTime in Table is not Null.

Full code:

```
private void receivingTableDataGridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, 
EventArgs e)
{
    if (receivingTableDataGridView.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
    {
        int selectedrowindex = receivingTableDataGridView.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
        DataGridViewRow selectedRow = receivingTableDataGridView.Rows[selectedrowindex];
        DateTime PostedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(selectedRow.Cells[2].Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Can you add de Exception Message and CallStack and the info stored in selectedRow.Cells[2].Value?

Comment: selectedRow.Cells[2].Value is datetime

Comment: use break point what is selectedRow.Cells[2].Value , selectedrowindex  and selectedRow  value

Comment: If the value really is a datetime, you don't need the ToDateTime call. What's the error (if any) if you leave it out?

Comment: If this exception opccurs, you obviously **have** null-values in your table.

Comment: @TheCity Without the error message and the real value its not posible help you without guess that information.

Answer (score 4):

Use Nullable DateTime but in null value Convert.ToDateTime return excaption.

```
 DataGridViewRow selectedRow = receivingTableDataGridView.Rows[selectedrowindex];

  DateTime? PostedDate =selectedRow.Cells[2].Value==null?null:Convert.ToDateTime(selectedRow.Cells[2].Value);
```

Answer (score 2):

`PostedDate` should be a `Nullable<DateTime>`(`DateTime?`), because it can be null if the value is `DbNull.Value`. You could use following code to check it:

```
DateTime? postedDate = null;
if(!System.Convert.IsDBNull(selectedRow.Cells[2].Value))
{
    postedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(selectedRow.Cells[2].Value);
}
```